# Ansible: Execute pre_tasks which ignore serial

Tags: ansible

I'm listing only two plays out of the entire playbook, as example:

```
- name: Kubernetes Tasks
  hosts: cluster
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  tags:
    - kubernetes
    - never
  tasks:
    - name: Import facts
      ansible.builtin.import_role:
        name: k3s
        tasks_from: facts

- name: Kubernetes Provisioning
  hosts: cluster
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: helm
    - role: k3s
  serial:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 5
  tags: kubernetes
```

The example listed above does not reflect the entire playbook complexity, but the end goal is to execute `pre_tasks` on all hosts, while roles follow the serial definition, all within a single play:

```
- name: Kubernetes Provisioning
  hosts: cluster
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Import facts
      ansible.builtin.import_role:
        name: k3s
        tasks_from: facts
  roles:
    - role: helm
    - role: k3s
  serial:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 5
  tags: kubernetes
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: So, your question is: the two plays you are showing are working but you’d rather have them in a single play, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.